# How to search for all the line items that use free-form custom criteria in DFP?

Tags: advertising, google-dfp, ad-targeting

I have a lot of line items and a lot of custom targeting parameters in DFP. Is there a way to search line items and find all matches that use a given targeting parameter?

Say I have a free-form targeting key called "City." I want to find all line items where the targeting criteria include a match on some value of "City."

Comment: Have you tried the search box under "Orders" -> "Line Items" -> "All line items"?